# java timer on current instance

Tags: java, timer, boggle

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class Boggle {
    Board board;
    Player player;
    Timer timer;
    boolean active;

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Boggle() {
        board = new Board(4);
        timer = new Timer();
    }

    public void newGame() {
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        String line = in.nextLine(); 
        player = new Player(line);
        active = true;

        board.shuffle();
        System.out.println(board);

        timer.schedule(new timesUP(), 20000);
        while(active) {
            String temp = in.nextLine();
            player.addGuess(temp);
        }
    }


    public void endGame() {
        active = false;
        int score = Scoring.calculate(player, board);
        System.out.println(score);
    }


    class timesUP extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            endGame();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Boggle boggle = new Boggle();
            boggle.newGame();

    }
}
```

I have the above class which should perform a loop for a given length of time and afterwards invoke an instance method. Essentially I need the loop in newGame() to run for a minute or so before endGame() is invoked on the current instance. However, using the Timer class I'm not sure how I would invoke the method I need on the current instance since I can't pass any parameters to the timertasks run method?

Is there an easy way to do this or am I going about this the wrong way? (note: this is a console project only, no GUI)

==========

code edited

I've changed the code to the above following the recommendations, and it works almost as I expect however the thread still doesnt seem to end properly. I was the while loop would die and control would eventually come back to the main method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `timesUP` (please change the name!) is an inner class, it already has a reference to the instance of `Boggle` which created it. (That wouldn't be the case if it were marked as `static`.) If you wanted to create an instance of `timesUP` associated with another instance, you'd do something like:

```
otherBoggle.new timesUp();
```

It's pretty odd syntax, admittedly :)

This doesn't fix the problem that Midhat identified, admittedly - but it means you don't need to worry about getting a reference to the outer class. Just call `endGame()` from within `timesUP.run()` and it will call it on the appropriate instance.

Comment: Ah, didnt realise inner classes inherit the reference. I'm a little confused to the problem Midhat is referring to though, could you clarify?

Comment: @hspim: Well, the timer is being called on one thread of execution - but you're still in the `while (true)` loop on the main thread. You can make `endGame()` store a flag saying "I'm done" and change your while loop to stop when that's changed... although you'll still have to wait for the player to finish their current guess.

Comment: tried using a boolean to achieve this but it doesnt seem to end the while loop. edited the code above to its current format. any advice?

Comment: @hspim: Try making it volatile - currently you don't have any synchronization between the threads. Don't forget that setting active to false won't stop the `nextLine()` call - you'll still need to wait for the player to hit return.

Answer (score 0):

You have blocking console input in the thread. The running time will be dictated by that. You can have the console input in a seperate thread, and add a timer in the current thread to kill the input thread after a minute, and call this.endGame()

Comment: The timer will already be running in another thread. I believe the current code will actually work in terms of displaying the existing guesses (when `timesUP.run()` calls `endGame()`, although it won't shut down cleanly. It also doesn't address the thread safety of displaying from one thread having added guesses from another.

Comment: Ah your right. endGame() gets called but the program doesn't exit as I was expecting. Im not familiar with threads though, could you give me hint where I go from here?